# How do I write a loop that prints out the numbers from 0 to 99 in Rust?

Tags: rust

> This question uses syntax that predates Rust 1.0, but the concepts are universal and many answers have been updated to reflect stable Rust 1.0.

This question is about a very basic thing that a programmer might try while learning Rust.

You couldn't ask a simpler question about the Rust language, I don't think, but I'm a programmer with 30 years experience, and I can't figure it out.

I think it has something to do with `int::range` and closures.

Here's what I wrote in a very early version of Rust (pre 1.0).

```
fn main() {
    int::range(0, 100, {|i| 
        io::println(i);
    });
}
```

This creates lovely error messages that I have no idea how to fix:

```
hello.rs:3:19: 5:2 error: mismatched types: expected `&fn(int) -> bool` but found `()` (expected fn but found ())
hello.rs:3 int::range(0, 100, {|i| 
hello.rs:4     io::println(i);
hello.rs:5 });
```

It's funny how it printed out my entire function body, but still I have no idea what that `&fn(int) ->b ool` thing means. I vaguely suspect that having a body of an iterator's closure not declare any return type is explicitly disallowed in Rust, which confuses me.

Comment: It's expecting a function that takes an int and returns bool. You're passing a function that takes nothing and returns nothing.  It's like a wrong type variable, except the variable is a method.

Comment: So you can't write a for loop in rust that doesn't return anything. I don't need the "side effect" of returning from the closure, but I guess I have no choice?

Comment: umm, don't know about rust in particular, just recognise the syntax.  (C# equivalents are Func<object, bool> & Action<object>)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rust certainly has come a long way! In Rust 1.0, ranges have some syntax sugar `start..end`, and implement the `Iterator` trait. Combined together, you can just say:

```rust
fn main() {
    for i in 0..100 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

[As of Rust 1.26](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/05/10/Rust-1.26.html), you can also use inclusive ranges:

```rust
fn main() {
    for i in 0..=99 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How do I include the end value in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43698191/155423)

Answer (score 9):

Rust 1.0 has changed quite a bit since this answer was posted. The right way to iterate like this today looks like:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..99 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

---

Original answer:

`int::range` takes a `&fn(int) -> bool`, which means a function that takes an `int` and returns a `bool`. Your function doesn't return a `bool`.

The typical way to deal with this is to use the `for` syntactical construct, which transforms your function from one that returns `()` into one that returns `bool`, which allows it to support `break` and `loop`.

```
for int::range(0, 100) |i| {
    io::println(fmt!("%d", i));
}
```

(note also that, at least in Rust 0.6, the proper syntax for the function is to put the `|i|` before the `{`)

---

The way higher-order iteration functions work in Rust is by using the `bool` return value to determine if it should continue iterating. A return value of `true` means to keep iterating, and a return value of `false` means to stop iterating. The `for` construct will rewrite the function to translate `break` and `loop` into the appropriate return statements. `break` will be translated into `return false` and `loop` into `return true`. It will also translate `return` statements into modification to a temporary flag variable from outside the loop (followed by a `return false`), which is then consulted after the iteration function is complete to determine if it should return from the outer function.

Comment: I think what's confusing me is how all the tutorials are a mix of rust 0.4 and early stuff not 0.6

Comment: @WarrenP: Yes, that's confusing to me as well, although I think the behavior of `for` is the same in both 0.4 and 0.6.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't compile because i is integer and println wants a string, and there's no such thing as int::str() anymore, I guess they changed that too.

Comment: @WarrenP: Yeah, I just noticed that. `fmt!` can fix that easily.

Comment: @WarrenP: As for `int::str()`, that's almost certainly the predecessor of `int::to_str()`.

Comment: So the above works, and `io::println( i.to_str() );` also works. got it.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my answer as well (and given you an upvote to boot).