# How do I include the end value in a range?

Tags: rust

I wanted to create a vector with 'a'..'z' values (inclusive).

This doesn't compile:

```
let vec: Vec<char> = ('a'..'z'+1).collect();
```

What's the idiomatic way to have `'a'..'z'`?

Comment: Does the type of `z` implement `Add<usize>`? If so, I think you just need to do `('a'..('z'+1))` due to operator precedence.

Comment: @bright-star no, it does not: *binary operation \`+\` cannot be applied to type \`char\`*

Comment: Wow, as I just found out, `('a'..'z').collect();` doesn't work either. rust 1.17. It seems I used this, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### Rust 1.26

[As of Rust 1.26](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/05/10/Rust-1.26.html), you can use "inclusive ranges":

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..=26 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

#### Rust 1.0 through 1.25

You need to add one to your end value:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 0..(26 + 1) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

This will not work if you need to include all the values:

- [How to iterate over all byte values (overflowing_literals in `0..256`)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32296410/155423)

---

However, you cannot iterate over a range of characters:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `char: std::iter::Step` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:14
  |
2 |     for i in 'a'..='z'  {
  |              ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::iter::Step` is not implemented for `char`
  |
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::ops::RangeInclusive<char>`
```

See [Why can't a range of char be collected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53971954/155423) for solutions.

I would just specify the set of characters you are interested in:

```
static ALPHABET: &str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

for c in ALPHABET.chars() {
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! With the hint of yours I ended up with `let abc: Vec<char> = (b'a'..b'z' + 1).map(|c| c as char).collect();` because there's not `std::iter::Step`

Comment: More generally: `(start as u32..end as u32 + 1).flat_map(std::char::from_u32)`.

Comment: Why did they decide to make the end of the range exclusive? It feels very unintuitive...

Answer (score 6):

Inclusive range feature stabilised and released as part of version [1.26](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/05/10/Rust-1.26.html). Below is valid syntax for inclusive range

```
for i in 1..=3 {
    println!("i: {}", i);
}
```