# How to translate "x-y" to vec![x, x+1, … y-1, y]?

Tags: rust, readability

This solution seems rather inelegant:

```
fn parse_range(&self, string_value: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let values: Vec<u8> = string_value
        .splitn(2, "-")
        .map(|part| part.parse().ok().unwrap())
        .collect();

    { values[0]..(values[1] + 1) }.collect()
}
```

- Since `splitn(2, "-")` returns exactly two results for any valid `string_value`, it would be better to assign the tuple directly to two variables `first` and `last` rather than a seemingly arbitrary-length `Vec`. I can't seem to do this with a tuple.
- There are two instances of `collect()`, and I wonder if it can be reduced to one (or even zero).

Comment: As long as you want to return a `Vec<u8>`, you need at least 1 collect

Answer (score 3):

## Trivial implementation

```
fn parse_range(string_value: &str) -> Vec<u8> {
    let pos = string_value.find(|c| c == '-').expect("No valid string");
    let (first, second) = string_value.split_at(pos);

    let first: u8 = first.parse().expect("Not a number");
    let second: u8 = second[1..].parse().expect("Not a number");

    { first..second + 1 }.collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=74a1dfb2c83f0ea005257821b71ac67b&version=stable)

I would recommend returning a `Result<Vec<u8>, Error>` instead of panicking  with `expect/unwrap`.

## Nightly implementation

My next thought was about the second collect. Here is a code example which uses nightly code, but you won't need any collect at all.

```
#![feature(conservative_impl_trait, inclusive_range_syntax)]

fn parse_range(string_value: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> {
    let pos = string_value.find(|c| c == '-').expect("No valid string");
    let (first, second) = string_value.split_at(pos);

    let first: u8 = first.parse().expect("Not a number");
    let second: u8 = second[1..].parse().expect("Not a number");

    first..=second
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", parse_range("3-7").collect::<Vec<u8>>());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `inclusive_range_syntax` fix the overflow in `"0-255"` that the first version has?

Comment: You could also avoid the `collect` by returning a `std::ops::Range<u8>` and not need nightly. Unfortunately you still need nightly to return `RangeInclusive`, but maybe one of these days...

Comment: In the nightly implementation I'd rather return the `RangeInclusive` from the function and leave turning it into a vector (or treating it as iterator) to the caller.

Comment: @CodesInChaos that's what I did. Well... I didn't returned `RangeInclusive`, but it's the callers decision to collect the result or do something else with it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of calling `collect` the first time, just advance the iterator:

```
let mut values = string_value
    .splitn(2, "-")
    .map(|part| part.parse().unwrap());

let start = values.next().unwrap();
let end = values.next().unwrap();
```

Do not call `.ok().unwrap()` — that converts the `Result` with useful error information to an `Option`, which has no information. Just call `unwrap` directly on the `Result`.

As already mentioned, if you want to return a `Vec`, you'll want to call `collect` to create it. If you want to [return an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423), you can. It's not bad even in stable Rust:

```
fn parse_range(string_value: &str) -> std::ops::Range<u8> {
    let mut values = string_value
        .splitn(2, "-")
        .map(|part| part.parse().unwrap());

    let start = values.next().unwrap();
    let end = values.next().unwrap();

    start..end + 1
}

fn main() {
    assert!(parse_range("1-5").eq(1..6));
}
```

Sadly, [inclusive ranges are not yet stable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43698191/155423), so you'll need to continue to use `+1` or switch to nightly.

---

> Since `splitn(2, "-")` returns exactly two results for any valid `string_value`, it would be better to assign the tuple directly to two variables first and last rather than a seemingly arbitrary-length `Vec`. I can't seem to do this with a tuple.

This is not possible with Rust's type system. You are asking for [*dependent types*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), a way for runtime values to interact with the type system. You'd want `splitn` to return a `(&str, &str)` for a value of `2` and a (`&str`, `&str`, `&str`) for a value of `3`. That gets even more complicated when the argument is a variable, especially when it's set at run time.

The closest workaround would be to have a runtime check that there are no more values:

```
assert!(values.next().is_none());
```

Such a check doesn't feel valuable to me.

---

See also:

- [What is the correct way to return an Iterator (or any other trait)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27535289/155423)
- [How do I include the end value in a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43698191/155423)

Comment: I don't like the implicitness of using `next()` twice (it's still implicit that there must be exactly two values), but the `unwrap()` tip and returning an iterator are both great!

Comment: @l0b0 I'm not sure you are using the word "implicit" the way that I understand it. Calling `next` seems very *explicit*, and the fact that there are two variables is also very *explicit*.

Comment: I mean that it's not explicit that we've consumed all the available entries in `values`. If I could say `(first, last)=` instead it would be a runtime error if the value was for example "5--6" or "5-6-". Currently I have to rely on less obvious logic: That `parse()` won't simply ignore leading or trailing dashes, and that I've given the right `n` to `splitn` - my original implementation used `n`=`1` because I intuited that `n` was the number of *splits* and not the number of returned items. If for whatever reason `n` is set to three there would be an undetected bug when handling invalid input.

Comment: *because I intuited that n was the number of splits and not the number of returned items* — that would be [because of me](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/979), you're welcome!

Comment: @l0b0 I seem to recall there being some suggestion of `impl FromIterator<T> for Result<(T, T, ...), NotEnoughItems>` which would permit something like that. However, I can't find it now. I think it was blocked waiting on const generics or some other future feature...