# Why can't a range of char be collected?

Tags: collections, rust, iterator

I'm trying to generate a vector containing lowercase ASCII characters. This more convoluted approach works:

```
let ascii_lowercase = (b'a'..=b'z').map(|b| b as char).collect::<Vec<char>>();
```

But this more straightforward one, which I came up with in the first place, does not:

```
let ascii_lowercase = ('a'..='z').collect::<Vec<char>>();
```

The error is:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `collect` found for type `std::ops::RangeInclusive<char>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:2:39
  |
2 |     let ascii_lowercase = ('a'..='z').collect::<Vec<char>>();
  |                                       ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `std::ops::RangeInclusive<char> : std::iter::Iterator`
          `&mut std::ops::RangeInclusive<char> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

Which is weird, because as far as I understand, there is a [blanket implementation of `Iterator` for `RangeInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeInclusive.html#impl-Iterator).

Is it impossible to use a range of chars as an iterator? If so, why? If not, what am I doing wrong? I'm using stable Rust 2018 1.31.1.

Comment: You missed `where A: Step`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT 2020-07-17:** since Rust 1.45.0, the trait `Step` is implemented for `char`, making `Range<char>` (and some other char ranges) work as an iterator. The code in the question now compiles without problem!

Old answer below.

---

The expression `b'a'..=b'z'` has the type `RangeInclusive<u8>` ([see on Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6bfa512bb7ea6d4be7163ff8dc4d72fd)) because the expression `b'a'` has the type `u8`: that's what the `b` in front of the character literal is for. On the other hand, the expression `'a'..='z'` (without the `b`s) has the type `RangeInclusive<char>`.

> [...] there is a blanket implementation of `Iterator` for `RangeInclusive`.

For one, this is not what we call "blanket implementation" (this is when the impl block is `for T` or `for &T` (or similar) with `T` being a generic type). But yes, there is an impl. But let's take a closer look:

```
impl<A> Iterator for RangeInclusive<A> 
where
    A: Step,   // <--- important
```

The `A: Step` bound is important. As you can see in [the documentation for `Step`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Step.html), this trait is implemented for all primitive integer types, but not for `char`. This means that there is no clear "add one" operation on characters. Yes, you *could* define it to be the next valid Unicode codepoint, but the Rust developers probably decided against that for a good reason.

As a consequence, **`RangeInclusive<char>` does not implement `Iterator`**.

So your solution is already a good one. I would probably write this:

```
(b'a'..=b'z').map(char::from).collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

The only real advantage is that in this version, `char` doesn't appear twice.

Comment: @Shepmaster Good find. But I think that question is mainly about the endpoint and that answer just incidentally also mentions the `char` "problem". Having a dedicated question for "char iterator" is better IMO.

Comment: Thanks! I figured there must be a difference between `char`s and `u8`s I was missing, but I can't read Rust that well yet, so I wasn't able to figure out that the root cause of "`RangeInclusive<char>` doesn't implement `Iterator`" is that `char` doesn't implement `Step`.

Thank you also for clarifying the usage of the term "blanket implementation", I'll be more careful in the future :)

Re: the dupe, I think SO did suggest it to me when I was composing this question, but the title felt so clearly not like my problem that I didn't even click it...

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that the iteration capabilities of range types depend on the `Step` trait ([see extended answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53972046)).
However, starting from [Rust 1.45](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/07/16/Rust-1.45.0.html), `char` also implements `Step` ([PR 72413](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/72413)), which means that the code in the question now works!

```
let ascii_lowercase: Vec<char> = ('a'..='h').collect();
assert_eq!(
    ascii_lowercase,
    vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
);
```